# Goodness of Fit (weighted least squared) using variance instead of standard deviation

Tags: variance, goodness-of-fit, calibration

Is goodness of fit measured by weighted least square sometimes done by using the variance instead of the standard deviation in the denominator?

What I mean is the following. Lets consider the following goodness of fit function: 
$$\chi^2  =\sum  ({ y(a)-f(a|\Theta ) \over \sigma^2})^2  $$

with $y(a)-f(a|\Theta ))$ as the difference between the empirical observations and the estimated model and $\sigma^2$ as the standard deviation for the empirical observations. 
Is there a form where I can use the variance for the empirical observations instead of the standard deviation in the denominator?

If yes: Are there any papers doing this?

If no: why is nobody doing this?

Comment: Do you have any reference to where you have seen this?